# Message Sequence chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, formatting, boxes

I'm drawing a `sequencediagram` with LaTeX. By now it looks like this:

[image]

- Is it possible to remove the grey boxes?
- Is it possible to put a space between handshake and `ws.connect`?

This is my Code:

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp!]
\begin{center}
    \fbox{
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread{c}{:Client}
        \newinst[4]{s}{:Server}

        \begin{call}
            {c}{Handshake}
            {s}{Handshake}
        \end{call}

        \begin{call}
            {c}{ws.connect}
            {s}{ws.connectes}
        \end{call}

        \mess{c}{ws.message}{s}
        \mess{s}{ws.message}{c}
        \mess{c}{ws.message}{s}

    \end{sequencediagram}
    }
\caption{WebSockets}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome To TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Please make your code compile by adding \document{class}, \usepackage{pkg}\begin{document}\end{document} etc. This makes it much easier for people to reproduce what you are seeing and potentially help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at `pgf-umlsd.sty` is not so difficult to find that by default, all `threads` are filled with `gray!30`. But being an optional parameter you can change it just declaring which color do you prefer: `\newthread[white]{c}{:Client}`. I've selected white because `none` draws transparent `threads` which don't cover the background dotted line.

Second question was more difficult because all call/message positions are based on several internal counters and harcoded factors. The best solution I could find was to `step up` the counter which places every call: `\stepcounter{seqlevel}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread[white]{c}{:Client}
        \newinst[4]{s}{:Server}

        \begin{call}
            {c}{Handshake}
            {s}{Handshake}
        \end{call}

        \stepcounter{seqlevel}
        \begin{call}
            {c}{ws.connect}
            {s}{ws.connectes}
        \end{call}

        \stepcounter{seqlevel}
        \mess{c}{ws.message}{s}
        \mess{s}{ws.message}{c}
        \mess{c}{ws.message}{s}

    \end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice, my latex skill improves from day to day
and if you want to hide the black thread line you have to override: \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[white]